# Fragments With RecyclerView not working, it's getting error 'No layout manager attached skipping entry.'

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

When I try Recyclerview With Fragments its getting error `Fragments With RecyclerView not working`. Its getting Error `No layout manager attached. Skipping entry`.

**My FrgamentList.java**

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
String [] names={"Nitin","Manish","Ankit","Hardik","Mayur","Mayank"};

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
Context context;
RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container,false);

    mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_nit);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    mAdapter= new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),names);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

   return v;
     }
 }
```

**RecyclerAdapeter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
String[] names;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[] names) {
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_list,parent,false);

    vh=new ViewHolder(v);
    return (ViewHolder) vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txt.setText(names[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return names.length;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txt;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_listtext);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow community. It is good practise to consider accepting and upvoting answers when you ask a question. It will help other user to know right one first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your created layout manager to RecyclerView

```
mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_nit);
LinearLayoutManager mLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

//add this line
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
```

Comment: I want Add Click Event . When I click on that name in fragment2 display description about that. How can i do that? Plz Help  @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a LayoutManager to recyclerView like this:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

or

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
```